# Pandas unexpected column reordering when using .rolling()

Tags: python, pandas

I've been tracking a strange bug, or at least a change of behavior in recent pandas versions (not sure when the change occurred, sometime between 0.16.2 --where it was working fine-- and 0.19.2).

Basically, I want to smooth out a few columns in a `DataFrame`, but I have a `MultiIndex` with dates and IDs, and the smoothing should be applied after unstacking the ID (i.e. for all IDs, for the selected columns).  If I do a `stack('id')` after an unstack, no problem, the order of columns is kept unchanged. But if the unstack is done after `df_fat.rolling(...).mean()` for example, then the columns become sorted alphabetically.  Further, assigning the smoothed columns back into the original frame gets the result assigned to the wrong columns, with pretty nasty results in our case.

Now, I know it is advisable for indexes (and columns) to be sorted, but I am quite surprised that the assignment in the last cell ([5] below) is done obviously wrong and without even a complaint from pandas.  Is that a bug in pandas?  Could there be a warning at least?

To summarize, I see two problems:

1. `.rolling().func` changes the column order: it sorts them alphabetically.
2. `slice = df` does not respect the column names (as a `.join` would) --it just plugs the values in.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
In[1]:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

str = """t,id,x,foo,bar
2012-01-01,A,0,100,1
2015-10-27,B,1,200,2
2015-11-15,B,2,300,3
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str), parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0,1]).sort_index()
df

Out[1]:
               x  foo  bar
t          id             
2012-01-01 A   0  100    1
2015-10-27 B   1  200    2
2015-11-15 B   2  300    3
```

Now, say I want to smooth the two columns `foo` and `bar`. First, make a 'fat' df so the smoothing can be done readily with `.rolling().mean()`. (Note also a `null_index` to preserve where NaNs are in the original):

```
In[2]:
feat_names = ['foo', 'bar']
df_fat = df[feat_names].unstack('id')
null_index = df_fat.isnull()
df_fat

Out[2]:
              foo         bar     
id              A      B    A    B
t                                 
2012-01-01  100.0    NaN  1.0  NaN
2015-10-27    NaN  200.0  NaN  2.0
2015-11-15    NaN  300.0  NaN  3.0
```

so far, no problem. In fact, stacking yields the original df, for the columns selected:

```
In[3]:
df_fat.stack('id')

Out[3]:
                 foo  bar
t          id            
2012-01-01 A   100.0  1.0
2015-10-27 B   200.0  2.0
2015-11-15 B   300.0  3.0
```

Now, let's do the smoothing:

```
In[4]:
df_fat = df_fat.rolling(center=False, window=2, min_periods=1).mean()
df_fat.stack('id')

Out[4]:
               bar    foo
t          id
2012-01-01 A   1.0  100.0
2015-10-27 A   1.0  100.0
           B   2.0  200.0
2015-11-15 B   2.5  250.0
```

Note how the columns have been sorted.  And then, when trying to assign back to the original, all hell breaks loose and column values are "plugged in" without regard for the column names:

```
In[5]:
df_fat[null_index] = np.NaN
df[feat_names] = df_fat.stack('id')
df

Out[5]:
               x  foo    bar
t          id               
2012-01-01 A   0  1.0  100.0
2015-10-27 B   1  2.0  200.0
2015-11-15 B   2  2.5  250.0
```

Note that explicitly reordering the columns on the right hand side of the assignment yields the expected result:

```
In[6]:
df_fat[null_index] = np.NaN
df[feat_names] = df_fat.stack('id')[feat_names]
df

Out[6]:
               x    foo  bar
t          id               
2012-01-01 A   0  100.0  1.0
2015-10-27 B   1  200.0  2.0
2015-11-15 B   2  250.0  2.5
```